# How to set an alert for a particular account?

Tags: java, android, alarm, user-accounts, vibration

How to set an alert for a particular account so that I can change the number every time?

MainActivity.java :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    smsContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtContent);
    smsNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNumber);
    btnConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm) ;
}
```

G.java :

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}
```

ReadSms.java :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        Toast.makeText(context, "message received . . .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String message = smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
            String number = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            MainActivity.smsContent.setText(message);

        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<receiver android:name=".ReadSms">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

How do I compare the incoming message number with the desired number?